# Configuring XAMPP to run Apache & MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, apache, xampp

I'm trying to get XAMPP set up to run Apache & MySQL for a the [Laravel](https://www.udemy.com/laravel-course/learn/v4/t/lecture/9541990?start=0) development environment that I need to start using.

When I first opened XAMPP, I couldn't start Apache because port 80 was already in use. I changed the port to 8080 as recommended by the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317372/xampp-port-80-in-use-by-unable-to-open-process-with-pid-4).

Currently, when I open XAMPP up, I get an error that says:

> 11:12:00  [Apache]    Problem detected!
>   11:12:00  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
>   11:12:00  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
>   11:12:00  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
>   11:12:00  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
>   11:12:00  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
>   11:12:00  [main]    Control Panel Ready

But when I click 'Start' for the Apache service, it starts successfully.

When I click 'Start' for the MySQL service, I get the message:

> 11:17:01  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...

and then nothing happens...

I tried doing what the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022809/xampp-mysql-shutdown-unexpectedly) suggests, and exited the server, deleted the `ibdata1` file, and restarted the server, but it just got to the same point, with the message

> 11:22:55  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...

then doesn't seem to do anything...

I came across the [Conflicting ports of MySQL and XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173242/conflicting-ports-of-mysql-and-xampp) question, and tried what the answer suggested- changing the port number in `my.ini` from 3306 to 3307, and adding the line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '3307';
```

to config.inc.php, but that doesn't seem to have resolved the issue.

Any know how I can get MySQL to start up successfully from XAMPP?

Comment: Do you have MAMP installed or any other varients? sometimes this can cause conflicts

Comment: No, only XAMPP...

Comment: Skype? I know skype uses port 80 from previous experience. `netstat -a -b` take a look and see what ports are in use after that. I know you said you changed it but it should hopefully give more insight. also change this in your httpd.conf in apache config aswell as your other config